# Using 'NONE' literal string in SQL where criteria seems to be getting confused with NULL data

Tags: sql-server

%It appears as though SQL is confusing 'NONE' with null in my environment but also recognizing 'NONE' somehow...

I have googled and searched StackOverflow. I see that NONE is a reserved word but I wouldnt expect that to matter as a string in quotes. Search terms included 'Reserved word in SQL where criteria' and ' 'NONE' in SQL where criteria' and nothing I found really helped.

All of the following commands are being ran directly through SQL server 2008 R2 SQL Server Management Studio. Query C does not give me the output I expect

```
Query A
SELECT COUNT (*)
from tbl 
WHERE id LIKE 'ABCV%' 
--20118 records

Query B
SELEC tbl
WHERE id LIKE 'ABC%' and fielda = 'NONE'
--10 records

Query C
SELECT COUNT (*)
from tbl
WHERE id LIKE 'ABC%' and fielda != 'NONE'
--15695 records (Why?? - I expect 20118 - 10 = 20108 records)



Extra - but possibly useful information



Query D
SELECT count(*)
from tbl 
WHERE id LIKE ABC%' and fielda is null
--4410 records

Query E
SELECT tbl
WHERE id LIKE 'ABC%' and fielda is not null
--15708
```

I appreciate any assistance or light anyone may be able to shed. Thank you!

Comment: The missing records would be found by.... SELECT COUNT (*)
from asset 
WHERE assetnum LIKE 'RFDEV%' and dvname is null.  Null can't be compared to as a string it will always return false in a boolean evaluation (null is the actual result and it gets evaluated to false)

Comment: Qry C change where to : `WHERE assetnum LIKE 'RFDEV%' and dvname != 'NONE' or devname is null` and  you should get the 20118 as expected.  Simply put.  NULL can't be compared in booleans.  it has to be handled as is null or is not null.  or you could use: `WHERE assetnum LIKE 'RFDEV%' and coalesce(dvname,'0') != 'NONE'`

Comment: Perfect! The Coalesce statement worked for me. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: yeah the 1st one should ahve had ()'s around the dvname so the or was inclusive to dvname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default result of comparation value with NULL is not neither TRUE nor FALSE. Result will be unknown (ELSE subtree will be run)
This behavior can be changed by ANSI_NULLS parameter. But usually you should use ISNULL() or COALESCE() function or check null values directly. Changing this parameter is really bad idea.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
DECLARE @id INT = NULL

-- 'unknown'
IF @id != 1
    SELECT 'no result'
ELSE
    SELECT 'unknown'

-- 'unknown'
IF @id = 1
    SELECT 'no result'
ELSE
    SELECT 'unknown'

-- 'now ansi_nulls off'
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
IF @id != 1
    SELECT 'now ansi_nulls off'
```

Answer (score 1):

`fielda` can be NULL.  Many people say "null value", but it's wrong: *NULL is **not** a value*.  NULL is *marker*, an indication that there is no value.  Both of these:

```
fielda  = 'NONE'
fielda != 'NONE'
```

are *false* for any NULL.  You might try

```
fielda is 'NONE'
```

That will yield either 10 or a syntax error.

If you find this confusing, join the club.  Many knowledgable people consider NULL a wart.  Some would ban it; I personally would make it an error to compare NULL to a value, whether with `=` or `!=`, or with `IN` or `EXISTS`.  Maybe one day....

Here's a tally for your 'ABC' rows:

```
Not Null and     'None' =    10 
Not Null and not 'None' = 15698
                          -----
Not Null                = 15708 
    Null                =  4410
                          =====
Total                   = 20118
```